# Trig substitution for $\int \frac{1}{x(x^2-9)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have done the integral $\int \frac{1}{x(x^2-9)}dx$ with partial fractions, and am now wondering how to do it with trigonometric substitution. All of the trig sub problems i've encountered have square roots in the denominator of the integrand. Any help or tips for my substitution would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x=3\sec\theta$, so that $x^2-9=9(\sec^2\theta-1)=9\tan^2\theta$ and $dx=3\sec\theta\tan\theta\,d\theta$. Then

$$\int{dx\over x(x^2-9)}=\int{3\sec\theta\tan\theta\,d\theta\over27\sec\theta\tan^2\theta}={1\over9}\int{\cos\theta\,d\theta\over\sin\theta}={1\over9}\ln|\sin\theta|+C$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer it totally eluded me.

Comment: You're totally welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Let $t=\frac1{x^2}$. Then

$$\int \frac{1}{x(x^2-9)}dx=\frac12\int \frac{dt}{9t-1}=\frac1{18}\ln|9t-1|+C$$

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use trig substitution, unless the question requires that you use it. If you factor out $x^2$ in the denominator, your integral becomes
$$ \int\frac{1}{x^3(1-\frac{9}{x^2})}$$
Then let $u=1-\frac{9}{x^2}\implies du = \frac{18}{x^3}dx\implies dx = \frac{x^3}{18}du$. The newly introduced $x^3$ on the numerator then cancels with the one in the denominator, and your integral becomes
$$ \frac{1}{18}\int\frac{1}{u} du$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \int \frac{1}{x\left(x^{2}-9\right)} d x \\
=& \frac{1}{9} \int\left(\frac{x}{x^{2}-9}-\frac{1}{x}\right) d x \\
=& \frac{1}{9}\left[\frac{1}{2} \ln \left|x^{2}-9\right|-\ln |x|\right]+C \\
=& \frac{1}{18} \ln \left|\frac{x^{2}-9}{x^{2}}\right|+C .
\end{aligned}
$$